# Won't boot from USB win XP

Tags: usb

I recently downloaded Ubuntu OS on my Win XP. I copied the download to a usb stick restart my computer with the USB drive as number 1 to boot from. The process won't even boot up it say disk error every-time I've done this a number of times and I don't to want use CD disk at this time cause I'm fresh out. Not sure what I done wrong. It downloaded fine on my desktop and transferred to my USB just fine but will not boot up. Any suggestions?

Thank you,
dave

Comment: How did you create the stick, with unetbootin or some program like it?  Did you hashcheck the downloaded iso?

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot just copy the iso to a usb the same way you would right-click on an iso and would then select burn from the given options. With the Windows operating system it is recommended that you use a program called "[universal pendrive linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)" to install the iso.

If you have already downloaded the iso file of Ubuntu, just decline to download the iso from the source after you select the OS from the list of OSs to install and then select the iso from file. Follow the instructions and you will end up with a working USB to boot Ubuntu from. Good Luck and have fun! Here's the link: [www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Finally, it sounds like you have the option to select the USB drive as the first drive in the order of bootloader devices but I feel it is important to also mention that some older computers do not have the option to boot from a USB in the BIOS settings.

Comment: Thank you-I will follow all instruction as given and see that this works.

Thanks again, David

Comment: Well, that all work just fine as described however once I booted my system then a display appeared with a list of Ubuntu steps of what I could do next, but nothing happen it froze on me several times not letting me continue with the install or just run separate. Now I'm stuck again not sure what to do next.

Comment: One other additional issue I discovered once I kept playing around with the system I received this error code: Error: PAE is diabled on this Pentium M ( PAE can potentially be enabled with Kernel Parameter " Forcepae " --this is unsupported, may cause unknown problems, and will taint the Kernel ) This Kernel requires ( PAE ) use a Kernel appropriate for your CPU.. I have no idea what this is can somebody comment on this and let me know what I need to do next to get my system up and running with Ubuntu?